# JSON parser crashes with objects

Tags: java, android, json

The next code receives a JSON reader based on an inputStream. When i try to parse String or Int it works fine. However, when i have one object, for example the object Name whose atributes are firstName and lastName Strings the parser does not works well. The JSON code have this form:

```
{
"name": {
"firstName": "Mikel",
"lastName": "Corcu"
}
}
```

The code that i use is the next, it crashes when i do reader.nextName() with intention of take the next String after the Name, at this case firstName and lastName:

```
public User formatUser(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

    User usuario = new User();
    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String user = reader.nextName();
        System.out.println("El objeto es:"+user);
        switch (user) { 
            case "name":
                Name nombre = new Name();
                reader.nextName(); // CRASH HERE
                nombre.setFirstName(reader.nextString());

                reader.nextName();
                nombre.setLastName(reader.nextString());

                usuario.setName(nombre);
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+usuario.getName().getFirstName());

                reader.skipValue();
                break;
            case "gender":
                usuario.setGender(reader.nextString());
                System.out.println("Genero: "+usuario.getGender());
                reader.skipValue();
                break;
            case "birthDate":
                /*Date birthDate =new Date();
                birthDate = stringToDate(reader.nextString());
                usuario.setBirthDate((java.sql.Date) birthDate);*/
                reader.skipValue();
                break;
            case "friendCount":
                usuario.setFriendCount(reader.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Numero de amigos: "+usuario.getFriendCount());
                reader.skipValue();
            default:
                reader.skipValue();
                break;
        }
    }
    reader.endObject();

    return usuario;
}
```

The logcat is the next:

```
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504): Error!
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 38 column 13 path $.name
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:800)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at com.hc.parsers.UserParser.formatUser(UserParser.java:47)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at com.hc.parsers.UserParser.leerUser(UserParser.java:32)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at com.hc.parsers.UserParser.readJsonStream(UserParser.java:23)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at com.hc.modelo.ObtencionDatosUsuario.doInBackground(ObtencionDatosUsuario.java:48)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at com.hc.modelo.ObtencionDatosUsuario.doInBackground(ObtencionDatosUsuario.java:1)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-10 11:53:47.857: E/ServicioRest(12504):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I dont understand correctly "Expected a name but was BEGIN_OBJECT". Thanks a lot.

EDIT 1: This is the complete parser class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.holacampus.api.domain.Name;
import com.holacampus.api.domain.User;

public class UserParser {

public User readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    // Nueva instancia JsonReader
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
    try {
        // Leer Array
        return leerUser(reader);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

}
public User leerUser(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    // Lista temporal 
    User user = new User();
    user = formatUser(reader);

    return user;
}

public User formatUser(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

    User usuario = new User();
    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String user = reader.nextName();
        System.out.println("El objeto es:"+user);
        switch (user) { //Cuando intenta parsear no encuentra estos case y entonces devuelve a null el usuario.
            case "name":
                Name nombre = new Name();
                reader.nextName(); // CRASH HERE
                nombre.setFirstName(reader.nextString());

                reader.nextName();
                nombre.setLastName(reader.nextString());

                usuario.setName(nombre);
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+usuario.getName().getFirstName());

                reader.skipValue();
                break;
            case "gender":
                usuario.setGender(reader.nextString());
                System.out.println("Genero: "+usuario.getGender());
                reader.skipValue();
                break;
            case "birthDate":
                /*Date birthDate =new Date();
                birthDate = stringToDate(reader.nextString());
                usuario.setBirthDate((java.sql.Date) birthDate);*/
                reader.skipValue();
                break;
            case "friendCount":
                usuario.setFriendCount(reader.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Numero de amigos: "+usuario.getFriendCount());
                reader.skipValue();
            default:
                reader.skipValue();
                break;
        }
    }
    reader.endObject();

    return usuario;
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public Date stringToDate(String fecha){
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    Date date= new Date();
    try {
        date = formato.parse(fecha);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

}

Comment: what package parser r u using?

Comment: Im not using parser packages, is one class that i created. I added it to the post.

Comment: fyi: you are usiing Gson package mate, :)

Comment: mate, the problem with your code is basically you are using too many reader.nextName();. which is not needed. just follow the example in : https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `name` is a JSONObject not a simple JSON field, that's why it is throwing this error. 
Just modify your code to parse it like a JSONObject :

```
case "name":

reader.beginObject(); //this indicates name a JSONObject
reader.nextName(); 
nombre.setFirstName(reader.nextString());
```

Comment: i <3 YOU hahaha, that was.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jMainObject;
String firstName, lastName;
jMainObject = new JSONObject("Your Server Response");

if(jMainObject.has("Name")){
    JSONObject jDataObject = jMainObject.getJSONObject("Name");
    firstName = jDataObject.getString("firstName");
    lastName = jDataObject.getString("lastName");
}else{
    firstName = jMainObject.getString("firstName");
    lastName = jMainObject.getString("lastName");
}

Log.i("Name", firstName+" - "+lastName);
```

**Done**

Comment: So, with this mode i dont need switch/cases. Correct?

Comment: Thanks @Hiren Patel, "Your Server Response" you are doing reference to HttpResponse object?

Comment: @Aszur, it would be your response which you are getting from server and might be you have already it.